# why is SeparableConv2D slower than Conv2D?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I've been experimenting with different types of convolution layers, to check their computational speeds. my code, in the beginning, was as follows.

```
def conv_block_A(layer):
    block = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(layer)
    block = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=196, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(block)
    block = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(block)
    block = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(block)
    block = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(block)

    return block
```

after going through a few blogs, I changed my code as

```
def conv_block_A(layer):
    block = tf.keras.layers.SeparableConv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(layer)
    block = tf.keras.layers.SeparableConv2D(filters=196, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(block)
    block = tf.keras.layers.SeparableConv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(block)
    block = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(block)
    block = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(block)

    return block
```

the training process became twice as fast on CPUs, but, the training has become very slow on Tesla T4. what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue with GPU's it was fixed in [#33836](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/33836). Also, you should update your GPU driver.
As a rule of thumbs speedup by doing separable convolution is more noticeable with large kernel sizes because of the overhead involving doing two convolutions might be larger than the speedups.

Comment: thank you for your help. but, this doesn't seem to solve my problem. I'm using
TensorFlow ==1.14.0
CUDA ==10.2
driver version ==440.33.01 
cudnn == 7.6.4
and still, it gets slow and sometimes it runs out of memory.
can you please help me on which versions to use.

Comment: still no improvement in speed with cudnn == 7.6.4

Comment: Have you tried running your code on google collab? and see if the problem persists.

Comment: yes, I tried running it in google collab and also I create a virtual machine with one v100 GPU in google compute engine. in both the cases, separable conv2d in extremely slow when compared to conv2d